# Problemas para detener la ejecución de un script en python

Tags: python, vscode, hilos

tengo un script en python, el cual lee primero un archivo dse configuracion json, con una estructura de procesos, grupos, satelites
Luego, con esa estructura inicia un ciclo anidado, y levanta en threads independientes observers que miran en carpetas definidas (en el json) por cambios.
Hasta ahi toodo va bien.. pero  mi problema es que cuando en la terminal del vscode intento parar la ejecucion (terminar los observers) ya no tengo contreol sobre la terminal.. es decir, el ctrl+c no funciona..  en ese momento tengo que eliminar el terminal, y crear uno nuevo para poder ejecutar nuevamente el script.

Aca el script..

previamente hay un diccionario con los datos (observador)

```
for observador in observadores:
    hilo = threading.Thread(name = observador, target=IniciaHiloObservador, args=(observador, ))    
    hilo.start()
```

luego en la funcion IniciaHiloObservador

```
def IniciaHiloObservador(Observador):
    observadorId = Observador[0]  #, sateliteName, datosConf
    pathImagesInPut = Observador[1]
    datos = Observador[2]
    observer = Observer()
    q = queue.Queue()
    observer.schedule(ProcesoPrincipal(q, observadorId, datos), pathImagesInPut, recursive=False)
    observer.start()
    try:
        while observer.is_alive():
            observer.join(1)
    except KeyboardInterrupt:
        observer.stop()
    observer.join()
```

y esta es la clase que contiene el codigo util de la aplicacion

```
class ProcesoPrincipal(FileSystemEventHandler):  
    def __init__(self, q, observadorId, datosConfig):
        self._q = q
        self._observadorId = observadorId       
        self._datosConfig = datosConfig         
        super().__init__()
        
    def on_any_event(self, event):
        action = {
            EVENT_TYPE_CREATED: "Creado",
            EVENT_TYPE_DELETED: "Eliminado",
            EVENT_TYPE_MODIFIED: "Modificado",
            EVENT_TYPE_MOVED: "Movido",
        }[event.event_type]
                
        if event.event_type == EVENT_TYPE_CREATED:
            print(f"Evento Detectado : {event.event_type}")
            print(f"Nombre Archivo   : {Path(event.src_path).name}")
            self._q.put(
                Path(event.src_path).name,
                action                    
                datetime.datetime.now().strftime("%H:%M:%S") 
            )
            #resto del codigo..
```

Alguna idea de como poder agregar codigo para que me responda al menos el ctrl+c en la consola??
Gracxias por leer.

Comment: ¿El terminal queda "colgado"? tal vez puedas insertar algún `sleep()` de algunos milisegundos para devolver el control a la terminal.

Comment: hola, el terminal no queda colgado..  el proceso sigue adelante ""observando"" las carpetas tal y como se requiere... de hecho, si copio algo a alguna de las carpetas que estan siendo observadas, el proceso contiunua sin problemas..  lo que no puedo hacer (desde la terminal) es quebrar el ciclo del observer, el cual esta corriendo en un thread.. intente poniendo un sleep, pero aun asi no reconoce el ctrl+c

Comment: La forma estándar es definir una variable booleana global que indica a todos los procesos si llego la hora de terminar. Luego tienes otro proceso que lee el teclado, detecta el CTRL-C y cambia la variable global.